# Converting json object to tsv format in java

Tags: java, json, csv, object, hashmap

I have the following class

```
public class Params {
    private String dataType;
    private Map<String, List<String>> group;
    private List<Aggregate> aggregates;
    private List<String> scene;
    private List<String> company;
    private List<Map<String, List<String>>> fit;
    private Map<String, String> params;
    private String tempo;
    private String id;
    private String valuation;
}
```

In order to convert it to a tsv, I have serialized it to json using:

```
  public String put(final Params parameter) {
    serializedParams = JsonSerializer.serialize(params);
}
```

So I get something like this as an output:

```
  {
      "dataType" : "abc",
      "group" : { },
      "aggregates" : [ ],
      "scene" : [ "AC" ],
      "company" : [ "pr" ],
      "fit" : [ {
        "prod" : [ "A1" ]
      } ],
      "params" : null,
      "tempo" : "note",
      "id" : "123",
      "valuation" : USD
    }
```

My eventual output is getting something like this (tab-separated):

abc AC pr prod A1 note 123 USD

I tried using :

```
parameter.getGroup.values()
```

This, however, only gives the values present in a format like [ val ].

How can I get all the values of the object simultaneously? Is it possible to get values from a map, list etc simultaneously without separate processing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite clear from your question exactly how you want to handle your data when generating your tabbed output for certain scenarios, but I'll try to provide some sample code to help you.

First, however, I want to say that it's not a good idea to serialize to JSON and then serialize JSON to tab separated values. You're doing 2 steps when you could be doing one, the JSON serialization doesn't get you any closer to your goal, and serialization is generally a costly process - you don't want to do it more than you have to.

So with that in mind here's a quick example of how you might implement a simple tab delimited serialization:

Since you have at least one custom object to deal with inside of your `Params` class (referring to the `List` of `Aggregate`objects) I would suggest creating an interface that your classes can implement to indicate they are able to be serialized into a tab delimited string.

I simply called this interface `TabSerializable`:

```
public interface TabSerializable {
    public String toTabbedString();
}
```

Next, I modified your `Params` class to implement this interface:

```
public class Params implements TabSerializable{
    //fields omitted for brevity.
    ...

    public String toTabbedString(){
        StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("\t");

        TabSerializer.addValue(dataType, joiner);
        TabSerializer.addValue(group, joiner);
        TabSerializer.addValue(aggregates, joiner);
        TabSerializer.addValue(scene, joiner);
        TabSerializer.addValue(company, joiner);
        TabSerializer.addValue(fit, joiner);
        TabSerializer.addValue(params, joiner);
        TabSerializer.addValue(tempo, joiner);
        TabSerializer.addValue(id, joiner);
        TabSerializer.addValue(valuation, joiner);

        return joiner.toString();
    }
    ...
}
```

I also created a sample `Aggregate` class which also implements this interface:

```
public class Aggregate implements TabSerializable{
    private String data;

    @Override
    public String toTabbedString() {
        return data;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Since you have mostly generic types of data structures like maps and lists I created the `TabSerializer` class to help transform those structures into tab delimited strings:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class TabSerializer {
    private static void addValuesFromMap(Map<?,?> obj, StringJoiner joiner) {
        for(Object key: obj.keySet()){
            Object value = obj.get(key);
            if(value == null){
                continue;
            }
            addValue(key, joiner);
            addValue(value, joiner);
        }
    }

    private static void addValuesFromList(List<?> arr, StringJoiner joiner) {
        for(int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++){
            Object value = arr.get(i);
            addValue(value, joiner);            
        }
    }

    public static void addValue(Object value, StringJoiner joiner){
        if(value == null){
            return;
        }
        if(value instanceof List){
            addValuesFromList((List<?>)value, joiner);
        }else if(value instanceof Map){
            addValuesFromMap((Map<?,?>)value, joiner);
        }else if(value instanceof TabSerializable){
            joiner.add(((TabSerializable) value).toTabbedString());
        }else{
            joiner.add(String.valueOf(value));

        }
    }
}
```

Based on the example you gave in your question I wrote the logic above to skip null values and the names of fields at the top level (those fields in the `Params` class).

Finally I created a class with a `main` to test the above logic:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainTabDelim {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Params params = new Params();
        params.setDataType("abc");
        List<String> scene = new ArrayList<>();
        scene.add("AC");
        params.setScene(scene);
        List<String> company = new ArrayList<>();
        company.add("pr");
        params.setCompany(company);
        List<Map<String, List<String>>> fit = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> fitInner = new ArrayList<>();
        fitInner.add("A1");
        Map<String, List<String>> fitMap = new HashMap<>();
        fitMap.put("prod", fitInner);
        fit.add(fitMap);
        params.setFit(fit);
        params.setTempo("note");
        params.setId("123");
        params.setValuation("USD");

//      Uncomment the following lines to see how Aggregate works:
//      List<Aggregate> aggregates = new ArrayList<>();
//      Aggregate ag = new Aggregate();
//      ag.setData("some_data");
//      aggregates.add(ag);
//      params.setAggregates(aggregates);

        System.out.println(params.toTabbedString());
    }
}
```

The output is:

> abc   AC  pr  prod    A1  note    123 USD

I hope this helps you to get started. Enjoy!

Comment: I have : private List<NamedTimeRange> timeRanges; It has start date, end date and name. Example:     "timeRanges" : [ {
    "name" : "2014",
    "startDate" : "2014-01-01",
    "endDate" : "2014-12-31"
  } ],  How can I print these values (2014, 2014-01-01, 2014-12-31) tab separated using the above code? I have a class called "NamedTimeRange.java".

Comment: Follow the example in the `Params` class - implement the `TabSerializable` interface by creating a method `toTabbedString`, use `TabSerializer` to process generic fields.

Comment: Is there a better way than calling "addValue" function so many times in Params class? Could that code be made more efficient?

Comment: `Params` is a custom object with many fields, calling `addValue` is being used to add those fields to the serialized `String`. I suppose you could use reflection to iterate over all of the fields, but generally reflection is costly and should be avoided when possible. If you could avoid using a custom class and instead use a generic structure like a `Map` then you could easily iterate over all the keys and values of that `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

Same CSV generate code you have to use, and only add a few things when you create the TSV file as below

```
 try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("src/main/resources/test2.tsv"),
            '\t',
            CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER,
            CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,
            CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END)) {
        writer.writeAll(dataLines);
    }
```

I used OpenCsV maven library